# CodeIgniter, PHPMailer & SendGrid Not Working on a cPanel-Based Host

Tags: php, codeigniter, email, smtp, phpmailer

I have CodeIgniter project running on a cPanel/centOS based host. The [CodeIgniter email class](https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/email.html) (running off of [phpMailer v 6.1.4](https://github.com/ivantcholakov/codeigniter-phpmailer)) is not working on this host, but is working locally and in other environments.

- When we run the code below on our cPanel-based host, we get an uninterpretable error from the PHPMailer debugging function:

  > The following SMTP error was encountered:  +�W��TV���:����;�D���q�� Unable to send email using PHP SMTP. Your server might not be configured to send mail using this method.
- The weird thing is that everything was working until two days ago, and nothing was changed (to my knowledge) on the code-level.
- When we check error logs we see the following:

> Severity: Warning --> stream_socket_enable_crypto(): Peer certificate
>   CN=`*.mywebhost.com' did not match expected CN=`smtp.sendgrid.net'
>   /home/myenv/public_html/system/libraries/Email.php

The above leads me to believe that:

- The host is utilizing some kind of configuration (such as "FKA SMTP Tweak") preventing us from connecting to SendGrid. (I toggled this on/off, but it didn't seem to to anything).
- There's some kind of SSL issue

I've been trying to diagnose with our host, but they have been rather unhelpful until now, so any insights would be most welcome and thanks in advance!

Please let us know if we can provide any more information and thank you in advance for your cooperation.

```
$config                     = array();
$config['useragent']        = 'PHPMailer';
$config['protocol']         = 'smtp';
$config['mailpath']         = '/usr/sbin/sendmail';
$config['smtp_host']        = 'smtp.sendgrid.net';
$config['smtp_user']        = 'USER';
$config['smtp_pass']        = 'PASSWORD';
$config['smtp_port']        = 587;
$config['smtp_timeout']     = 5;
$config['smtp_crypto']      = 'tls';
$config['wordwrap']         = true;
$config['wrapchars']        = 76;
$config['mailtype']         = 'html';
$config['charset']          = 'iso-8859-1';
$config['validate']         = true;
$config['priority']         = 3;
$config['crlf']             = "\n";
$config['newline']          = "\n";
$config['bcc_batch_mode']   = false;
$config['bcc_batch_size']   = 200;

$this->load->library('email');
$this->email->initialize($config);
$this->email->from('my@email.com', 'Your Name');
$this->email->to('my@email.com');
$this->email->subject('Email Test');
$this->email->message('Testing the email class.');
$this->email->send();
show_error($this->email->print_debugger());
```

Comment: what is the smtp_host your hosting company recommends to use? I have a setting with `protocol='smtp'` and `smtp_host='**mail**.domain.com'` on a shared hosting environment

Comment: We're using SendGrid because it has worked reliably in many other cases. As well everything was working until three days ago

Comment: I guess it's up to your hosting provider to give you more insights on what they changed lately. if they are "unhelpful" consider moving to another provider...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've got this in your config:

```
$config['smtp_host']        = 'smtp.sendgrid.net';
```

But you're seeing this in your errors:

```
Peer certificate CN=*.mywebhost.com did not match expected CN=smtp.sendgrid.net
```

This tells us that your hosting provider is redirecting SMTP traffic to their own mail server. Because this redirection is invisible to you, it's left up to TLS to spot that the expected name does not match the presented certificate, and abort the connection, because this is in effect a man-in-the-middle attack.

You need to ask your provider to stop redirecting your SMTP traffic, or find a new hosting service.

Comment: Just to be clear, do you mean 'hosting provider' (when I read "ISP" I think of "internet service provider"...which I don't think would have any control over the redirection). If this is a cPanel-based system, do you know where I would look to disable the local SMTP server?

Comment: Yes I do mean your hosting provider. Given the wildcard certificate presented I would guess this is done at a level above your cPanel controls, so you would need to ask your hosting provider. I know, for example, that scaleway.com works this way. The problem is not that you have a local mail server, it’s that a firewall is redirecting your traffic.

Comment: OK, that makes sense and thank you so much for taking the time. One last question, if we're running our DNS through CloudFlare, would we have to manage it through there or would it be on the server/hosting side of things?

Comment: No, DNS is not a factor - it’s the outbound network traffic being redirected by the hosting provider. If you try to ‘openssl s_client -connect smtp.google.com:465` from your server, I would expect to see it presenting the same cert.

Comment: Thank you so much for your insights! After a ton of wrangling with my host, we finally got this to work. Ultimately, it seems that it was a combination of issues.

Comment: Glad it worked out - please click the check mark next to my answer!

Comment: Just did and thanks. If I might make a suggestion. Maybe your solution could be reworded to "hosting provider" instead of "ISP" ...your solution is spot on, I just feel like ISP/Internet Service Provider might cause some confusion.

Answer (score 0):

NOTE: This solution may vary, but this is what resolved my issue. *(Please see @Syncro's comment, it's more precise...the 'solution' below was how I resolved things with the hosting provider in my particular case).*

My hosting provider had to:

- Make sure that the server would accept outgoing connections
- Restart the firewall
- Make sure that FKA SMTP Tweak was disabled.

That said, I've tested SendGrid's [PHP API Library](https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-php) and am probably going to go with that. I think PHPMailer is a great solution, but in some cases (such as was mine), certain hosting providers might interfere with it.